# Submeter formulario com evento quando checando radio buton de bootflap

Tags: javascript, html, javascript-eventos, layout-responsivo

Estou usando esta biblioteca de HTML responsive (http://bootflat.github.io/documentation.html) e quero submeter um formulário quando clico num radio button. O problema é que como existem várias "camadas" de divs por cima do radio button, este não é checado diretamente, e então o evento do submit não ocorre.

Como posso resolver isto?

Código

Antes de carregar no browser:

```
<div style="position: relative;" class="iradio_flat">
<input type="radio" name="diploma" id="diploma" value="DS" onchange='this.form.submit();'>
</div>
<label id="diploma_DS" class="radio_label" for="diploma">Diploma</label>
```

Depois de carregar no browser:

```
<div style="position: relative;" class="iradio_flat">
    <div class="iradio_flat checked" style="position: relative;">
        <input name="diploma" id="diploma" value="DS" checked="" onchange="this.form.submit();" style="position: absolute; top: -20%; left: -20%; display: block; width: 140%; height: 140%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 0%; border: 0px none; opacity: 0;" type="radio">
        <ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: -20%; left: -20%; display: block; width: 140%; height: 140%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 0%; border: 0px none; opacity: 0;"></ins>
    </div>
</div>
<label id="diploma_DS" class="radio_label" for="diploma">Diploma</label>
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como fazer submit de formulario quando checando radio buton de bootflap](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/250541/como-fazer-submit-de-formulario-quando-checando-radio-buton-de-bootflap), você não precisa criar uma outra pergunta, aguarde alguém responder.

Answer (score 0):

Se o seu radio button é "sobrescrito" depois que a página termina de carregar e você deseja que seja assim, ou não tem como mudar fácil, atribua o evento de click no elemento que está "acima" do seu radio button.

Para verificar isso aperto o botão direito sobre ele e vá até a opção "inspecionar elemento" do seu navegador e encontre exatamente o seletor que deve atribuir o evento de click.

Atribua um id no seu form e modifique o exemplo abaixo para sua realidade:

```
$(function() {
    $('#div_que_esta_por_cima').click(function() {
        $('#id_do_formulario').submit();
    });
});
```